# Cache solution for Dapper when using stored procedures (MSSQL)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, dapper

I'm using **Dapper** mainly for calling **stored procedures** in the database **MSSQL 2008 R2**.I do not have classes that map to database tables. Most of the data ends up in `IEnumerable <Dynamic>` and is transmitted to the grid on the screen.

Is there a ready to use solution for data buffering that I could use? (I need to use it on the MVC).

The data in the database are both static and dynamic in nature.I use the repository model to access the data.

Comment: I've thrown some thoughts together, but please let me know if I missed the point of your question.

Answer (score 6):

Dapper doesn't include any inbuilt *data* caching features (although it uses extensive caching internally for the meta-programming layer): it aims itself squarely at the ADO.NET stuff - however, you could use pretty much any off-the-shelf caching component, including the HTTP runtime cache (`HttpContext.Current.Cache`), or the newer `ObjectCache` etc implementations. Because these just take objects, it should work fine.

If you are using a *distributed* cache (maybe via app-fabric, redis, or memcached) then you'd need the data to be serializable. In that scenario, I would strongly suggest using formal POCO types for the binding, rather than the `dynamic` API. As an example, in-house we use dapper to populate POCOs that are annotated with protobuf-net markers for serialization, and stored via BookSleeve to redis. Which sounds more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: I was thinking more about a mechanism between my code and the database. I am doing a query, it checks for new data in the database, if so it returns directly from the database or otherwise from the cache. Just as ELMAH http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ it to be somewhat independent of my code. Elmah captures my exceptions and log them. Cache should capture my query to the database transparently. I guess I demand Santa Claus?

Comment: @Tomasito "checks for new data in the database" is tricky: an active cache is always tricky. For that, at SE we use a combination of dapper and booksleeve (redis) - Redis provides a consistent cache and pub/sub, so we can have multi-layer cache: we can store it in the local machine's memory, and use the pub/sub to invalidate it. So making the change becomes "store to db, and also issue a 'pub' so that all machines remove it from their local memory". Plumbing that together doesn't take much - and in my mind it is better to have 20 lines of your own utility code that lets you work with

Comment: @Tomasito whichever tools you choose, than to use some all-encompassing library/framework that forces you to use specific tools.